# Shopping advice: upgrade Finale, or buy Dorico?

Tags: notation, software, finale

I'm dusting off my old notation software, and find myself in the dilemma of whether to upgrade my `Finale 2012` into the 2019 version, or discard it and go for `Dorico`; the new hot and cool software.

`Finale` is an old trusted workhorse, but the 2012-version have a lot of quirks, and probably a lot of spaghetti code has carried over to the newer iterations. There are a lot of things that `Dorico` presumably does better than `Finale` e.g. automatic formatting), but also some features are currently lacking (like pitch before duration).

As long as Steinberg keeps placing their money behind `Dorico`, it will probably keep being developed. However, what are the chances that MakeMusic will step up their game and upgrade the features of `Finale` to compete on user-friendlyness?

Switching regularly between software is a pain, so any choice made will probably be for the long term. What are the pros and cons of choosing `Finale` or `Dorico`?

Comment: We won’t really have an answer for you here, and you might also consider Musescore.

Comment: StackExchange is a question-and-answer site where people are supposed to build commonly utilizable externalized knowledge through well-formed narrow questions, and "correct" answers to them. Not vague subjective views and opinions, but more like measurements and hard truths and facts. Through a formalized system of rules and mechanisms we take steps towards a new world with less human deficiencies. Hooray! LOL About _music_? The whole concept is like from some geek's wet dream. In other words, you are not supposed to ask for opinions here. :D

Comment: FWIW, Dorico has now implemented pitch before duration input. Since 2012, Finale has implemented very little.

Comment: That’s my impression as well. After using Dorico pro 3.0 for roughly a year, note input was the only area where Dorico was really inferior to Finale in terms of features (inputting series of notes with varying durations were a royal pain). With version 3.1 this hole has been plugged, and finally there are no reasons for looking back.